# React / JSX - remove menu items if sibling drop-down menu already has value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple Component / controlled function that lets the user choose an item from three different drop-down menus. I am currently tinkering with how to arrange the state/prop passing. The menu items for each drop-down menu are identical for each three, and they do not change. Still, there may need to be some kind of information passed at the event listner since the goal is to ensure there are no repeats in the users chosen menu items. In other words, when the user chooses something from one box, the other two boxes should remove that item from their choices (and again when the user chooses a second item). Here is the relevant code:

```
function SelectBox(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [strategy, setStrategy] = React.useState('');

    const handleChange = event => {
        setStrategy(event.target.value);
    };

    const textMap = {
        1:'Top pick',
        2:'Second pick',
        3:'Third pick'
    };

    return (
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">Strategy {props.selectBox.id}</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-helper-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select-helper"
                    value={strategy}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                >
                    <MenuItem value="">
                        <em>None</em>
                    </MenuItem>
                    {props.strategies.map(strategy => (
                        <MenuItem value={strategy}>{strategy}</MenuItem>
                    ))}

                </Select>
                <FormHelperText>{textMap[props.selectBox.id]}</FormHelperText>
            </FormControl>
    );
}

export default SelectBox;
```

Thus far I managed to pass props `id` down to each select box, and that allowed me to set helper text accordingly.

#### Edit

As suggested, I lifted the state up so that my menu items are now populated dynamically instead of hardcoded as before. However, I'm not sure that lifting the state solves the sibling comparison problem. (Note: I left the pre-lifted state event handler in for convenience, can assume it's now a prop in this scope that is sourced from state in another file)

State from that file is:

```
  state = { 
    selectBoxes: [
        {id:1, strategies:['A','B', 'C','D','E']},
        {id:2, strategies:['A','B', 'C','D','E']},
        {id:3, strategies:['A','B', 'C','D','E']},
    ]
 }
```

### Question

How would I approach event listner logic for sibling drop-down menus to ensure there are no repeats of an item?

Comment: Key concept: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html